# What is the simplest and cheapest way to dynamicly get method name in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-4.5

I would like to put a mathod name into a string but I also don't want use hard-coded value. Instead, I'd like to obtain the name dynamicly by reflection. I've used the following, **working** statement:

```
"The method is called " + new Action(MyMethod).Method.Name;
```

I think that creating an `Action` delegate is semantically inappropriate. It suggest that there will be a method invocation but instead, there will be a reflection. I'm looking for something like **typeof** operator or **GetType** for class but on method level.

Is the pattern `Delegate.Method.Name` act as the best and standard approach to achieve my goal?

---

I meant **not current** method.

Comment: As per your comment on Ehsan's answer, what error are you getting? If your on about the compiler error then how is it supposed to know what method you changed its name to? This is why you should use the refactoring tools to rename a method

Comment: There is no compilation error. I'm asking about different, better solutions or a confirmation that the current one is a standard manner to achieve the objective.

Comment: It sounds like your trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist, your question is extremely unclear

Comment: @Sayse The code is working but I am here to figure out if it is the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the best solution:

1. Create static class `ReflectionExtensionMethods`:

   ```
   public static class ReflectionExtensionMethods
   ```
2. Add several methods for `Action`, `Action<T>`, etc., `Func<T>`, `Func<T1, T2>` etc. Here is an example of an `Action`:

   ```
   public static string GetMethodName(this Type @this, Expression<Action> expression)
   {
       return GetMethodNameInternal(@this, expression);
   }
   ```
3. The internal part that checks whether given expression and its body is valid:

   ```
   private static string GetMethodNameInternal(Type @this, MethodCallExpression bodyExpression)
   {
       if (bodyExpression == null)
           throw new ArgumentException("Body of the exspression should be of type " + typeof(MethodCallExpression).Name);

       var member = bodyExpression.Method;
       if (member.MemberType != MemberTypes.Method)
           throw new ArgumentException("MemberType of the exspression should be of type " + MemberTypes.Method);

       if (!object.Equals(@this, member.DeclaringType))
           throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property owner.");

       return member.Name;
   }
   ```
4. Usage for instance member:

   ```
   var owner = new Foo();
   var methodName = typeof(Foo).GetMethodName(() => owner.VoidMethod());
   ```
5. Usage for static memeber:

   ```
   var methodName = typeof(Foo).GetMethodName(() => Foo.StaticVoidMethod());
   ```

`ReflectionExtensionMethods` may be further complemented by methods that will return the names of properties and other memebers.

Answer (score 2):

[MethodInfo.CurrentMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod.aspx) should give you the name of current method

```
"The method is called " + MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```

Comment: I've edited my question. Actually the method is not the current one. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: if not current method then which method?

Comment: Any method of the current class. E.g. The class have two methods A and B. I am in method A and want to obtain dynamicly the name of B. The name of B may change in the future to C. If I wrote "B" then my compiler would not warn me about inconsistent message that still uses "B" instead of up-to-date "C".

Comment: how are you thinking of specifiying which method. Your question is similar to this , Your name is unknown nobody will tell me what is your name but i want to know your name. Not Possible

Comment: Ehsan is right, it isn't possible, you could use [GetMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td205ybf.aspx) and guess away at what the method would be but there isn't any way of knowing what method your thinking of calling

Comment: My question is: _I know your name now, but it may changed. So I don't want to remember your name but instead I will ask (how, and who <-- my question point) for your name each time when I required it_.

Comment: who is the problem here. language will do what it is asked to do. if you don't know who how will language know it?>

Comment: In my question is an example of implementation: `new Action(MyMethod)`. If `MyMethod` change its name to `NewMethod`, the compiler will show an error in the line, where `MyMethod` is used (assuming that there is no more methods with such name and arguments). That can be also utilized by refactor process.

Comment: In my solution _who_ is `Action` and _how_ is its `Method` property.

Comment: In your answer about the current method _who_ is `MethodInfo` and _how_ is `GetCurrentMethod()`.

Comment: If I create an `Action` delegate, it will know about its method and compiler is capable of checking its correcteness. I thought about something similar to **typeof** operator for a method. I don't want to instantiate a delegate in order to use it for unrelated purpose. If I see in code typeof (class) I think - there will be a reflection. If I see new Action(method) I think - there will be invocation.

Comment: You say typeof. But question is typeof what? you don't know that

Comment: @yBee You commented: `...the compiler will show an error...` - It's even better than that - Usually, when changing a method name, you'd refactor automatically to change all occurrences and your code will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

use MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first approach.

1. Create a static class called *MethodInfo* (same name as *System.Reflection.MethodInfo*). Same name is reasoned due to the fact, that you rarely need to explicitly refer to the original type. However, you naturally look for the solution right there.

   ```
   public static class MethodInfo
   {
       public static System.Reflection.MethodInfo From(Func<string, int> func)
       {
           return func.Method;
       }

       // Other members for Action<T>, Action<T1, T2> etc.
       // Other members for Func<T>, Func<T1, T2> etc.
   }
   ```
2. Consider there is a class MyClass, that has MyMethod method:

   ```
   class MyClass
   {
       static int MyMethod(string s) { return default(int); }
   }
   ```
3. Use the class and its members as follows (The key part):

   ```
   "The method is called " + MethodInfo.From(MyClass.MyMethod).Name;
   ```
4. That is more self descriptive, easier to use and concise than:

   ```
   "The method is called " + new Func<string, int>(MyClass.MyMethod).Method.Name
   ```